# How to get new messages using gmail api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I'm writing a Google Chrome browser extension. It uses gmail-api and I want to receive incoming messages coming to the email address of the user who is logged in. How do I implement this in the background script in terms of code. I know that gmail api uses post requests such as watсh, then I don’t know how to implement the code so that I can see messages that would come in real time and my background script would be updated during this event.

My application uses the methods of pull alerts, and accordingly the documentation says that I should use requests such as 
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/acknowledge

How can I use all this in my code so that my script is constantly updated when I receive a new message and is it even possible in javascript?

```
function POST_request(method,url,_async,params)
{
    let xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method,url,_async);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + current_token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    return(xhr.responseText);
}

let tmp={
            "topicName":"projects/myprofect/topics/mytopic",
            "labelFilterAction":"include",
            "labelIds": ["INBOX"]
        };
        console.log(POST_request("POST","https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch",false,tmp));
```

This query works by returning the view body

```
{
 "historyId": "678576",
 "expiration": "1555318376357"
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the solution you have currently?

Comment: I do not understand how to implement the method of receiving notifications, how to use the methods that I listed above?

Comment: You might want to start by reading this.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: I have already read it, there is too little information about the implementation from the side of the client.  Basically, there is information about how to do server-side implementation.

Comment: you shouldn't implement  push notifications on a client.  Your server should be listening to the changes and then preforming actions on the changes when they come.